# clr.dll Crash on windows service

Tags: c#, .net

My application is c# windows service running on Windows Server 2008 R2. It crashes every now and then with the following error

Faulting application name: Fusion_Ingestion_Service.exe, version: 1.1.0.3, time stamp: 0x59428da5
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.34209, time stamp: 0x5348961e
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x0000e233
Faulting process id: 0x49ac
Faulting application start time: 0x01d30c3353dbd043
Faulting application path: 
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 8bbc1f2b-7844-11e7-b6c9-00155d018b91

I have tried the following

1. Installed .NET framework 4.6 and changed my application to 4.6 but still crashes. I thought it would use the 4.6 version of clr.dll but it still uses 4.0.3019.
2. Changed my application to x86 but still crashes

Any ideas as to how to find what the problem is

Comment: Show us your project references

Comment: @DennisLarisch just added references picture

Comment: I think the refrences are not really your problem, there was definietly a bug in the Framework 4.0 which got a hotfix, but I cant find the download link for it

Comment: @DennisLarisch when I upgrade to version 4.6, why is the clr.dll used still 4.0.3019?

Comment: Where do you see the .net version of the clr.dll? So I can check which version is mine

Comment: Just added a download link for this hotfix in my answer

Comment: @DennisLarisch Thanks for the fix. Is this fix for .net version 4.5 or 4.6 or it does not matter?

Comment: It is for Framework 4 in general I think https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/2640103

Comment: @DennisLarisch. This fix cannot be applied to my windows server 2008. I get an error 'KB2640103 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your compute'

Comment: Do you use 64 or 32 bit?

Comment: @DennisLarisch 64 Bit

Comment: hmm this hotfix seems to be for 32bit only...

Comment: after installing .net 4.5 and 4.6 did your rebuild your application and restarted the server?

Comment: Yes I did but still crashes

Comment: It is a very, very nasty mishap, about the worst thing that can happen to a program.  Corruption of a stack frame is the underlying cause, excessively difficult to diagnose.  The CLR takes the blame, but it merely detected the damage, it didn't cause it.  The check was added as a counter-measure against malware, stack corruption is the traditional way to get data turned into malicious code.  For all we know it is doing what it is supposed to do, protecting your server against an attack.  Only a full minidump of the crashed process gives you a shot at finding the cause.

Comment: @HansPassant When you say "Corruption of a stack frame is the underlying cause", could it be that the code causes it? Also every time the service is started, the stack frame is all fine and my code corrupts?

Comment: I am not going to send you off on a wild goose-chase that is unlikely to produce results.  I strongly recommend you buy the help that you need, this requires black-belt skills.  Consider calling Microsoft Support for example.

Answer (score 0):

The given exception code indicates a stack buffer overflow during runtime. Unfortunately without any source code or more details on the crash I cannot help you debug the issue here.

For general debugging tips for issues of this kind, see this answer (ignore the stack if you can't capture one yourself): https://stackoverflow.com/a/14206133/3966590

See the following MSDN answer and related resources on how to debug the issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/aa84a49e-6bfe-4b89-928a-ea477e73c07e/clr-exception-0xc0000409?forum=clr