# Does an appcrash with a STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW in a .Net application mean the stack overflow occured in native code?

Tags: c#, .net, stack-overflow, crash, ntdll

I get an appcrash with execution code c00000fd (STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW) in ntdll.dll.

Does that mean there was a stack overflow somewhere in native code, outside my managed code? Because for managed code, we have `System.StackOverflowException`. But there is none in my case, and no stack trace that could provide a clue.

Comment: look at the call stack: likely you have recursion in your .Net Code. Often that happens when a Property refers to itself....

Comment: @MitchWheat I wish there was a call stack - there was none left for me to investigate

Comment: @MitchWheat for the non-native speaker - what does that refer to? I'd love to laugh, too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant catch `System.StackOverflowException` any more

> Starting with .Net 2.0 they can only be caught in the following
> circumstances.
>
> - The CLR is being run in a hosted environment where the host specifically allows for StackOverflow exceptions to be handled
> - The stackoverflow exception is thrown by user code and not due to an actual stack overflow situation (Reference)

Although the error says it occurred in *ntdll.dll*  it is most likely caused form your code.

My first steps would be to add, or turn on your highest debug logging in production, so you can try to narrow down where it's happening and the circumstances.

Second I'd start debugging (attaching the debugger) and scrutinising that method class until you find it. Most likely it's due to some recursion, that's the first place I'd start looking.

---

**Additional Resources and references**

[C# catch a stack overflow exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599219/c-sharp-catch-a-stack-overflow-exception/1599237#1599237)

[How to find the source of a StackOverflowException in my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721841/how-to-find-the-source-of-a-stackoverflowexception-in-my-application)

[How to debug System.StackOverflowException without link to source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196981/how-to-debug-system-stackoverflowexception-without-link-to-source-code)

[How do I prevent and/or handle a StackOverflowException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206820/how-do-i-prevent-and-or-handle-a-stackoverflowexception)

[How to debug a stackoverflowexception in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733878/how-to-debug-a-stackoverflowexception-in-net)

[Troubleshooting Exceptions: System.StackOverflowException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6sxk224.aspx)

[StackOverflowException Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stackoverflowexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

> In the .NET Framework 1.0 and 1.1, you could catch a
> StackOverflowException object (for example, to recover from unbounded
> recursion). Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, you can’t catch a
> StackOverflowException object with a try/catch block, and the
> corresponding process is terminated by default. Consequently, you
> should write your code to detect and prevent a stack overflow. For
> example, if your app depends on recursion, use a counter or a state
> condition to terminate the recursive loop.